# KnockoutJS Performance: Only Render Elements that are Currently in View (Clean/Destroy Others)

Tags: performance, knockout.js, viewport, knockout-3.0

I am developing an application using KnockoutJS which intends to show pages/slides in a long, scrollable list.

Each of these pages has some advanced WYSIWYG capabilities as well as a ton of other tools & data attached.

However, as the number of pages/slides grows, I am noticing huge performance hits.

Therefore, I would like to change to a way that only renders the slides/pages that are in the viewport. Once you scroll past an item, I want KnockoutJS to destroy whatever it rendered before and, instead, render whatever has come into the viewport. Items that are destroyed should be replaced with a placeholder li-tag (until you scroll back to them).

#### What works so far

So far so good, I have put together a JSFiddle which nicely shows how only the "visible" items have their observable "inView" set to true. 
Take a look at the demo showing you how the viewmodel responds to scrolling: https://jsfiddle.net/1xxy6q83/

#### What's missing

The issue, however, is to get the conditional display working. Whenever I try to mix/match `foreach` and `if`, it stops working.
What I am looking for is that Knockout only renders what's seen in the viewport. As an item moves out of view, Knockout should clean it up, remove any events and instead render a very simple placeholder li-tag which ensures the list doesn't jump about.

Comment: Try using `template` bindings, and changing the bound variable as you scroll out of view, rather than `if` bindings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `template` bindings where the template name is based on the value of `inView`:

```
function Page(page) {
  var self = this;
  this.page = ko.observable(page);
  this.inView = ko.observable(false);
  this.templateName = function() {
    return self.inView() ? 'complex' : 'placeholder';
  };
}
```

The binding looks like:

```
    <ul data-bind="foreach: pages">
      <li data-bind="inview: $data">
        <div data-bind="template: templateName()">

        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

And [here's an updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wu0zfLhj/1/). I put a time delay on the setting of `inView` so you can see the template-swapping happening as you scroll.

Comment: Thank you Roy - this works perfectly and is nice and straightforward! Upon first glance, this managed to reduce the memory footprint multi-fold.

Comment: Note that that's a great solution if one have <10000 rows (also, adding `hidden` attribute to a placeholder div may improve performance). Beyond that, it doesn't scale well, and scrolling becomes sluggish.

Comment: Please don't make people scroll through tens of thousands of records. :)